# impossible count query with eloquent in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, join, model, eloquent

I am trying to count the likes of the users posts. In other words, not how many posts THEY LIKED but how many of THEIR POSTS were liked grouped by users.

While in **SQL** it would be straight forward :

```
SELECT users.name, COUNT(posts.id) AS likes_count FROM `posts` JOIN likes ON posts.id = likes.likable_id JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id GROUP BY posts.user_id
```

I can't find a way with eloquent. Any idea ? I have many problems of this type when i need info on lots of relations, eloquent is really a pain or am i the one not doing things right here ?

Keep in mind that i'd like it to stay efficient just like with PhalconsPHP ORM or Java's spring data

my tables for this example

- users : id, name, email
- posts : id, user_id, title, content
- likes : id, user_id, likable_id, likable_type (which is always POST
  for now)

Comment: If you're okay with raw queries you can try Model::select(DB::raw('query'))->get(); , example -- $users = DB::table('users')->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))->where('status', '<>', 1)->groupBy('status')->get();

Comment: Well this doesn't answer to my question here you are querying only one table while the information I need is across three tables

Comment: no i mean you can use your raw query instead, hence gave an example

Comment: the problem is raw sql joins doesn't give an eloquent model as an answer